# Are they ok to say "You put the blue Lego brick on the yellow one halfway. Please put it all the way on!" and "Please screw the cap all the way on"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Your child doesn't put Lego bricks on each other completely and screw the cap on the bottle completely. There are always gaps between them as showed in the following picture.

[image]

Are these correct expressions?

***-You put the blue brick on the yellow one halfway. Please put the blue one all the way on.***

***-You screwed the cap back on the bottle halfway. Please screw the cap all the way on.***

Comment: I used to call those chunky pieces "duplo", in Italy that was their name, they made especially for toddlers and small fingers. The plastic pieces should hold together without being tightly screwed or properly fitted because toddlers lack the dexterity and physical strength in their small fingers. Let the child just enjoy  him or herself exploring their new world and toys without telling them how to do everything.

Comment: 'Push the blue brick right down.' 'Make sure the cap is properly screwed on', or 'screwed all the way on' or 'down'.

Comment: @KateBunting, I like the phrase "right down". Does "right" mean "completely" in this case? If so, then when to use "right" and when to use "all the way"?

Comment: Yes, it does. You can say 'all the way down' if you want. There is no single right way to describe the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say this in many different ways. For example, you could say

> Son, push the blue piece a bit more so that there is no space/gap between the two pieces. They should fit tightly.

> Screw the bottle cap fully or Screw the bottle cap all the way until it's tight.

Because you are talking to a child, it is perhaps more important to ensure that your expressions are easy to understand. You don't always have to use the most appropriate words/phrases for your purpose; just word things in a way that is clear for the child to understand.